# dvdauthor Can only have 128 commands for pre, post, and cell commands

Tags: dvd, dvdauthor

I create bash script to archive my audio CD archive onto DVD with menus. Result dvdauthor.xml with title menu of artists list and 9 menus with artist's songs list. It is 67 songs.

```xml
<dvdauthor jumppad="0"><vmgm><menus><video format="pal" aspect="4:3"/>
  <pgc entry="title"><!-- MENU 1 LIST OF ARTIST -->
    <button name="button01">g0=button; g1=0; g10=0; g11=0; jump menu 2;</button>
...
    <button name="button08">g0=button; g1=0; g10=0; g11=0; jump menu 9;</button>
    <button name="shuffle">g0=0; g1=0; g10=1; g11=random(8); (...) if(g11==8) jump vmgm menu 9;</button>
    <pre>if(g11>0) g11=random(8); (...) if(g11==8) jump vmgm menu 9; g10=0; (...) if(g1>0 and g0==8192) jump vmgm menu 9; if(g0 gt 0) button=g0; else button=9216;</pre>
  </pgc>
  <pgc><!-- MENU 2 ARTIST 1  -->
    <button name="button01">g1=button; g10=0; jump title 1;</button>
    ...
  <pgc><!-- MENU 9 ARTIST 8 -->
...
    <button name="button06">g1=button; g10=0; jump title 66;</button>
    <button name="button07">g1=button; g10=0; jump title 67;</button>
    <button name="shuffle">g1=0; g10=10; g11=random(8); (...) if(g11==8) jump title 67;</button>
    <button name="artlist">g1=0; jump menu 1;</button>
    <pre>if(g10>0) g11=random(8); (...) if(g11==8) jump title 67; if(g0 == 8192 and g1 gt 0) button=g1; else button=9216; g1=0;</pre>
  </pgc></menus></vmgm>
<titleset><!-- TITLE 1 SONG 1 --><menus><pgc entry="root"><vob file="0.mpg"/></pgc></menus>
  <titles><video format="pal" aspect="4:3"/>
    <pgc><vob file="Song1.mpg" chapters="0:00,1:43,2:13,2:53,04:19.03"/>
      <pre>g11=0;</pre>
      <post>g11=2; if(g10==1)call vmgm menu 1; call vmgm menu 2;</post>
    </pgc>
  </titles>
</titleset>
 ...
<titleset><!-- TITLE 67 SONG 67 -->
<menus><pgc entry="root"><vob file="0.mpg"/></pgc></menus>
<titles><video format="pal" aspect="4:3"/>
  <pgc><vob file="Song67.mpg" chapters="0:00,1:03,2:38,03:56.44"/>
    <pre>g11=0;</pre>
    <post>g11=1; if(g10==1)call vmgm menu 1;if(g10==0) call vmgm menu 2; call vmgm menu 9;</post>
  </pgc>
</titles>
```

So, there is 67 'pre' in titles and 9 in menus. And 67 'post' in titles. It is 143 and more than 128. And DVD plays with no problems.
But if I add one more menu with 7 songs, get "ERR: Can only have 128 commands for pre, post, and cell commands."

Then I rescript and remove 'pre' from all titles. Then I have and 10 menus with 'pre' and 74 'post' in titles. And no 'pre' in tiles. It is 84 now and less than 128. But I get the same error "ERR: Can only have 128 commands for pre, post, and cell commands."
I have 74 buttons with songs, 10 'shuffle' buttons and 9 'back' buttons. It is 93 buttons.

"The `<pre>` and `<post>` sections of a PGC put together can contain no more than 128 VM instructions". How count instructions?

ADDITIONAL NOTES

I've changed

```
<button name="shuffle">g0=0; g1=0; g10=1; g11=random(8); (...) if(g11==8) jump vmgm menu 9;</button>
```

to itself and dvdauthor accepts additional about 10 songs

```
<button name="shuffle">g0=0; g1=0; g10=1; g11=random(8); jump vmgm menu 1;</button>
```

Next I've tried modify 'pre' in all 70 titleset title and it seems has no effect.

```
<pre>g11=0;</pre> --> <pre>g11=0; g3=random($num);g4=random($num);g5=random($num);g6=random($num);g7=random($num);g8=random($num);g9=random($num);</pre>
```

I've tried jumps; in every titleset menu too, but failed to auto activate command button.

AND LAST NOTES

I made a script that accepts 99 songs if you use 2 screens to select artists. It is strange that in this case there are more pre/post than there would be one artist selection screen.
Here is shortened davdauthor.xml

```xml
<dvdauthor jumppad="0">
  <vmgm>
    <menus><video format="pal" aspect="4:3"/>
      <pgc entry="title"><!-- MENU 1 DVD GLAM ROCK -->
        <button name="button01">g0=0; g1=button; g3=0; jump vmgm menu 2;</button>
        <button name="button02">g0=0; g1=button; g3=0; jump vmgm menu 3;</button>
        <button name="shuffle">g0=1; g1=0; g2=0; g3=random(5)+0; jump vmgm menu 1;</button>
        <button name="artlist">jump vmgm menu 4;</button>
        <vob file=".dvdauthor/01.mpg" pause="inf"/>
        <pre>if(g3==100)jump vmgm menu 4; if(g3>2) jump vmgm menu 3; if(g3>0) jump vmgm menu 2; g0=0; if(g2>0 and g1==1024) jump vmgm menu 2; if(g2>0 and g1==2048) jump vmgm menu 3; if(g1 gt 0) button=g1; else button=3072;</pre>
      </pgc>
      <pgc><!-- MENU 2 EUROPE -->
        <button name="button01">g0=0; g2=button; jump title 1;</button>
        <button name="button02">g0=0; g2=button; jump title 2;</button>
        <button name="shuffle">g2=0; g0=2; g3=random(2)+0; jump vmgm menu 2;</button>
        <button name="artlist">g2=0; jump vmgm menu 4;</button>
        <vob file=".dvdauthor/02.mpg" pause="inf"/>
        <pre> if(g3==1) jump title 1; if(g3==2) jump title 2; if(g1 == 1024 and g2 gt 0) button=g2; else button=3072; g2=0;</pre>
      </pgc>
      <pgc><!-- MENU 3 SUPERTRAMP & ROGER HODGSON -->
        <button name="button01">g0=0; g2=button; jump title 3;</button>
        <button name="button02">g0=0; g2=button; jump title 4;</button>
        <button name="button03">g0=0; g2=button; jump title 5;</button>
        <button name="shuffle">g2=0; g0=3; g3=random(3)+2; jump vmgm menu 3;</button>
        <button name="artlist">g2=0; jump vmgm menu 4;</button>
        <vob file=".dvdauthor/03.mpg" pause="inf"/>
        <pre> if(g3==3) jump title 3; if(g3==4) jump title 4; if(g3==5) jump title 5; if(g1 == 2048 and g2 gt 0) button=g2; else button=4096; g2=0;</pre>
      </pgc>
      <pgc><!-- MENU 4 GLAM ROCK -->
        <button name="button01">g0=0; g11=button; g3=100; jump vmgm menu 5;</button>
        <button name="button02">g0=0; g11=button; g3=100; jump vmgm menu 6;</button>
        <button name="shuffle">g0=1; g11=0; g12=0; g3=random(4)+5; jump vmgm menu 4;</button>
        <button name="artlist">jump vmgm menu 1;</button>
        <vob file=".dvdauthor/04.mpg" pause="inf"/>
        <pre>if(g3==100)g3=0; if(g3>7) jump vmgm menu 6; if(g3>5) jump vmgm menu 5; g0=0; if(g12>0 and g11==1024) jump vmgm menu 5; if(g12>0 and g11==2048) jump vmgm menu 6; if(g11 gt 0) button=g11; else button=3072;</pre>
      </pgc>
      <pgc><!-- MENU 5 T.REX (pop) -->
        <button name="button01">g0=0; g12=button; jump title 6;</button>
        <button name="button02">g0=0; g12=button; jump title 7;</button>
        <button name="shuffle">g12=0; g0=2; g3=random(2)+5; jump vmgm menu 5;</button>
        <button name="artlist">g12=0; jump vmgm menu 1;</button>
        <vob file=".dvdauthor/05.mpg" pause="inf"/>
        <pre> if(g3==6) jump title 6; if(g3==7) jump title 7; if(g11 == 1024 and g12 gt 0) button=g12; else button=3072; g12=0;</pre>
      </pgc>
      <pgc><!-- MENU 6 VA SONGS -->
        <button name="button01">g0=0; g12=button; jump title 8;</button>
        <button name="button02">g0=0; g12=button; jump title 9;</button>
        <button name="shuffle">g12=0; g0=3; g3=random(2)+7; jump vmgm menu 6;</button>
        <button name="artlist">g12=0; jump vmgm menu 1;</button>
        <vob file=".dvdauthor/06.mpg" pause="inf"/>
        <pre> if(g3==8) jump title 8; if(g3==9) jump title 9; if(g11 == 2048 and g12 gt 0) button=g12; else button=3072; g12=0;</pre>
      </pgc>
    </menus>
  </vmgm>
  <titleset><!-- TITLE 1 EUROPE/Europe-Catch That Plane -->
    <menus><pgc entry="root"><vob file=".dvdauthor/0.mpg"/></pgc></menus>
    <titles><video format="pal" aspect="4:3"/>
      <pgc><vob file="DVD GLAM ROCK/EUROPE/Europe-Catch That Plane.mpg" chapters="0:00,1:11,3:04,04:46.84"/>
        <!-- g3-next titleset; g4-random partition; g5-random artist -->
        <pre>g3=0;g4=random(5)+0;g5=random(2)+0;</pre>
        <post>g3=2; if(g0==1)g3=g4; if(g0>1)g3=g5; call vmgm menu 1;</post>
      </pgc>
    </titles>
  </titleset>
  <titleset><!-- TITLE 2 EUROPE/Europe-Children Of The Mind -->
    <menus><pgc entry="root"><vob file=".dvdauthor/0.mpg"/></pgc></menus>
    <titles><video format="pal" aspect="4:3"/>
      <pgc><vob file="DVD GLAM ROCK/EUROPE/Europe-Children Of The Mind.mpg" chapters="0:00,0:30,3:15,04:27.85"/>
        <!-- g3-next titleset; g4-random partition; g5-random artist -->
        <pre>g3=0;g4=random(5)+0;g5=random(2)+0;</pre>
        <post>g3=3; if(g0==1)g3=g4; if(g0>1)g3=g5; call vmgm menu 1;</post>
      </pgc>
    </titles>
  </titleset>
  <titleset><!-- TITLE 3 SUPERTRAMP & ROGER HODGSON/Supertramp-Breakfast in America -->
    <menus><pgc entry="root"><vob file=".dvdauthor/0.mpg"/></pgc></menus>
    <titles><video format="pal" aspect="4:3"/>
      <pgc><vob file="DVD GLAM ROCK/SUPERTRAMP &amp; ROGER HODGSON/Supertramp-Breakfast in America.mpg" chapters="0:00,1:27,02:36.32"/>
        <!-- g3-next titleset; g4-random partition; g5-random artist -->
        <pre>g3=0;g4=random(5)+0;g5=random(3)+2;</pre>
        <post>g3=4; if(g0==1)g3=g4; if(g0>1)g3=g5; call vmgm menu 1;</post>
      </pgc>
    </titles>
  </titleset>
  <titleset><!-- TITLE 4 SUPERTRAMP & ROGER HODGSON/Supertramp-Child of Vision -->
    <menus><pgc entry="root"><vob file=".dvdauthor/0.mpg"/></pgc></menus>
    <titles><video format="pal" aspect="4:3"/>
      <pgc><vob file="DVD GLAM ROCK/SUPERTRAMP &amp; ROGER HODGSON/Supertramp-Child of Vision.mpg" chapters="0:00,0:59,1:53,02:49.89"/>
        <!-- g3-next titleset; g4-random partition; g5-random artist -->
        <pre>g3=0;g4=random(5)+0;g5=random(3)+2;</pre>
        <post>g3=5; if(g0==1)g3=g4; if(g0>1)g3=g5; call vmgm menu 1;</post>
      </pgc>
    </titles>
  </titleset>
  <titleset><!-- TITLE 5 SUPERTRAMP & ROGER HODGSON/Roger Hodgson-Hai Hai -->
    <menus><pgc entry="root"><vob file=".dvdauthor/0.mpg"/></pgc></menus>
    <titles><video format="pal" aspect="4:3"/>
      <pgc><vob file="DVD GLAM ROCK/SUPERTRAMP &amp; ROGER HODGSON/Roger Hodgson-Hai Hai.mpg" chapters="0:00,1:40,2:16,2:43,3:19,3:46,05:31.20"/>
        <!-- g3-next titleset; g4-random partition; g5-random artist -->
        <pre>g3=0;g4=random(5)+0;g5=random(3)+2;</pre>
        <post>g3=1; if(g0==1)g3=g4; if(g0>1)g3=g5; call vmgm menu 1;</post>
      </pgc>
    </titles>
  </titleset>
  <titleset><!-- TITLE 6 T.REX (pop)/T.Rex-Jupiter Liar -->
    <menus><pgc entry="root"><vob file=".dvdauthor/0.mpg"/></pgc></menus>
    <titles><video format="pal" aspect="4:3"/>
      <pgc><vob file="GLAM ROCK/T.REX (pop)/T.Rex-Jupiter Liar.mpg" chapters="0:00,0:30,1:00,03:38.16"/>
        <!-- g3-next titleset; g4-random partition; g5-random artist -->
        <pre>g3=100;g4=random(4)+5;g5=random(2)+5;</pre>
        <post>g3=7; if(g0==1)g3=g4; if(g0>1)g3=g5; call vmgm menu 4;</post>
      </pgc>
    </titles>
  </titleset>
  <titleset><!-- TITLE 7 T.REX (pop)/T.Rex-Space Boss -->
    <menus><pgc entry="root"><vob file=".dvdauthor/0.mpg"/></pgc></menus>
    <titles><video format="pal" aspect="4:3"/>
      <pgc><vob file="GLAM ROCK/T.REX (pop)/T.Rex-Space Boss.mpg" chapters="0:00,0:30,1:00,02:44.96"/>
        <!-- g3-next titleset; g4-random partition; g5-random artist -->
        <pre>g3=100;g4=random(4)+5;g5=random(2)+5;</pre>
        <post>g3=8; if(g0==1)g3=g4; if(g0>1)g3=g5; call vmgm menu 4;</post>
      </pgc>
    </titles>
  </titleset>
  <titleset><!-- TITLE 8 VA SONGS/ELO-Four Little Diamonds -->
    <menus><pgc entry="root"><vob file=".dvdauthor/0.mpg"/></pgc></menus>
    <titles><video format="pal" aspect="4:3"/>
      <pgc><vob file="GLAM ROCK/VA SONGS/ELO-Four Little Diamonds.mpg" chapters="0:00,0:30,1:00,2:00,04:04.94"/>
        <!-- g3-next titleset; g4-random partition; g5-random artist -->
        <pre>g3=100;g4=random(4)+5;g5=random(2)+7;</pre>
        <post>g3=9; if(g0==1)g3=g4; if(g0>1)g3=g5; call vmgm menu 4;</post>
      </pgc>
    </titles>
  </titleset>
  <titleset><!-- TITLE 9 VA SONGS/Jeff Lynne-When The Night Comes -->
    <menus><pgc entry="root"><vob file=".dvdauthor/0.mpg"/></pgc></menus>
    <titles><video format="pal" aspect="4:3"/>
      <pgc><vob file="GLAM ROCK/VA SONGS/Jeff Lynne-When The Night Comes.mpg" chapters="0:00,0:30,1:00,03:12.16"/>
        <!-- g3-next titleset; g4-random partition; g5-random artist -->
        <pre>g3=100;g4=random(4)+5;g5=random(2)+7;</pre>
        <post>g3=6; if(g0==1)g3=g4; if(g0>1)g3=g5; call vmgm menu 4;</post>
      </pgc>
    </titles>
  </titleset>
</dvdauthor>
```

Into 8.5G DVD almost fits 6G DVD's VOB's and 2.5G flac's.

```
AUDIO_TS
VIDEO_TS
VTS
VTS  ALICE  COOPER
VTS  ALICE  COOPER  (hits)
VTS  BILLY  IDOL
VTS  BON  JOVI
VTS  ELO  &  JEFF  LYNNE
VTS  EUROPE
VTS  FRANZ  FERDINAND  (pop)
VTS  FRANZ  FERDINAND  (songs)
VTS.SHUFFLE
VTS  SUPERTRAMP  &  ROGER  HODGSON
VTS  SWEET
VTS  T.REX  (pop)
VTS  URIAH  HEEP
WAV  ALICE  COOPER
WAV  ALICE  COOPER  (hits)
WAV  BILLY  IDOL
WAV  BON  JOVI
WAV  ELO  &  JEFF  LYNNE
WAV  EUROPE
WAV.FLAC
WAV  FRANZ  FERDINAND  (pop)
WAV  FRANZ  FERDINAND  (songs)
WAV.SHUFFLE
WAV  SUPERTRAMP  &  ROGER  HODGSON
WAV  SWEET
WAV  T.REX  (pop)
WAV  URIAH  HEEP
```

All items are linked, so we virtually have 40G songs on 8,5G DVD.